# How do I reference a constructor with parameters using EditForm C#?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, blazor, blazor-editform

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship. A Company should be able to have many Boards. I have set up my model with such a relationship. However, I'm not sure how I call the correct constructor? as I initialize the object using the EditForm on my Create_Company page.

##### Company

```cs
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Founded { get; set; }

        public List<Board> Boards { get; set; }

        public Company()
        {
        }

        public Company(string name, DateTime founded)
        {
            Name = name;
            Founded = founded;
            Boards = new List<Board>();
        }
    }
```

I know how to do this using:

```cs
private Company Company { get; set; } = new Company("", new DateTime());
```

But not my current way of doing it:

##### Create_Company

```cs
@page "/create_company"

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject HttpClient Http

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary oi oi-arrow-left" @onclick="GoToReadCompany"></button>
    <h3 class="text-center">Create Company</h3>
</div>

<hr />

<hr />

<EditForm Model="Company" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" @bind-Value="Company.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Company.Name)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="CompanyFounded" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Founded</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputDate id="CompanyFounded" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Company.Founded" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Company.Founded)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private void GoToReadCompany()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/read_companies");
    }

    private Company Company { get; set; } = new Company();

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Companies", Company);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/read_companies");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred for POST company");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you create the company object in your create_company page the way you know how (by passing in the string & datetime as parameters)? This will initialize your List<Board>. Also, can you edit your post and ask a question?

Comment: I want the user to fill in the form and then use those parameters not create an empty object. Also I've edited so my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be not how to call constructor, but when. You could use a new object when the user submits. Then use the new company object.

```
    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            Company newCompany = new Company(Company.Name, Company.Founded);

            var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Companies", newCompany);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/read_companies");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred for POST company");
        }
    }
```